# MongoDB- Query Embedded Document, but Projection Showing Path to key/value?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

So basically I want

```
 db.scoreFacts.find(
  {"instrumentRanges.flute.minPitch": {$gte: 0, $lte:56}}, 
  {"instrumentRanges.flute.minPitch": 1})
```

to return

```
{ "_id" : "Bach_Brandenburg5_Mov1.xml", "minPitch" : 50 }
```

but instead I get:

```
{ "_id" : "Bach_Brandenburg5_Mov1.xml", "instrumentRanges" : { "flute" : { "minPitch" : 50 } } }
```

Essentially the path to "minPitch" is returned, which is not what I need. How can I achieve my desired output with only .find() (no map, etc)? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this with a standard `.find()` query. If you wish to alter the document structure, look into using an `aggregate()` call. You can then use projection to define the resulting field(s) you desire.

For example:

```
db.scoreFacts.aggregate([
    { $match: {"instrumentRanges.flute.minPitch": {$gte: 0, $lte:56}} },
    { $project: {"minPitch": "$instrumentRanges.flute.minPitch"} }
]);
```

For more information, please see the [relevant documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/). Additionally, take a look at the prerequisite [aggregation pipeline section](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/).

Note: I have not tested the above query myself, so you may need to alter it somewhat to get the behavior you want.